# Post ,ultiple photos to Facebook without proper permissions

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posting

I have a website, where a user can upload his own text and photos and after that thay can post them to facebook. But if I use PHP I have to get permissions from Facebook adminisration for that.

In order to avoid getting permisions, I use Facebook javascript SDK for that and post photos with it like this:

```
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
            message: 'Message text',
            link : 'www.site.com',
            picture : 'www.site.com/picture.jpeg',
        }, function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log(response.error);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

But there is a problem with that: I can not post multiple photos like this to a user's wall in the same post. How can I post to a user's wall text and multiple photos in the same post with Facebook JS SDK without permissions from Facebook administration?

P.S.: posting is not supposed to be automatic, it should be with confirmation dialog in popup window. Maybe, you know how to do this with PHP SDK, or even combined solution PHP SDK + JS SDK.

Comment: it does not metter what sdk you are using, you always need the same permission: publish_actions. and posting multiple photos at once is not possible.

Comment: why not? there are services like amplifier that post automatically to facebook group or feed multiple photos in the same post.

Comment: they are most likely using a trick (creating an unpublished album and stuff). stackoverflow is full of threads about that question. either way, without permission there is NO posting at all.